# PyPlot - Tricky axis color and labeling issues

Tags: date, pandas, matplotlib, plot, yaxis

I am fairly new to Matplotlib. This idea behind this figure is to graph temperature highs and lows. I've run into trouble with the xaxis and right yaxis.

For the xaxis, the color of the font doesn't want to change even though I call `tick_params(labelcolor='#b6b6b6')`. Also, the dates should only span from Jan - Dec. For unknown reasons, Matplotlib is prepending an extra Dec and appending an extra Jan, causing the text to flow outside of the graph's spine bounds. I want to remove these extra months.

For the right yaxis, I'm not sure I understand the use of subplots properly. I want to convert the ˚C temperatures in the left yaxis to ˚F and use the converted temps for the secondary yaxis.

### Here's some code to reproduce something similar to what I've got.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# generate some data to plot
highs = np.linspace(0, 40, 365) # these numbers will escalate instead of fluctuate, but the problem with the axes will still be the same.
lows = np.linspace(-40, 0, 365)

date_rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', '12/31/2015', freq='D')

data = {'highs': highs, 'lows': lows}
to_plot = pd.DataFrame(data, index=date_rng)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot the basic data
lines = ax.plot(date_rng, to_plot['lows'], '-',
                date_rng, to_plot['highs'], '-')

# get the axes reference
ax1 = plt.gca()

# fill in between the lines
ax1.fill_between(date_rng,
                to_plot['lows'], to_plot['highs'],
                facecolor='#b6b6b6', # gradient fillbetween
                alpha=.2)

# set the xaxis to only 12 months and space the names.
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15, interval=1))

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))

for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.tick1line.set_markersize(0)
    tick.tick2line.set_markersize(0)
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('center')

# add a right y axis and set all yaxis properties
ax1.set_ylim([-50, 50])

# change the color and sizes scheme 
info_colors = '#b6b6b6'
bold_colors = '#777777'

# graph lines
ax1.lines[0].set_color('#e93c00') # top redish orange
ax1.lines[1].set_color('#009ae9') # btm blue
plt.setp(lines, lw=.8, alpha=1)

# spines
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
for pos in ['bottom', 'right', 'left']:
    ax.spines[pos].set_edgecolor(info_colors)

# set the title
plt.title('Record Temps, 2005-15: Ann Arbour, MI', fontsize=10, color=bold_colors)

# ticks
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', color=info_colors, labelcolor=info_colors, length=5, direction='out', pad=7, labelsize=8)

# add a legend and edit its properties
leg = plt.legend(['Highs','Lows'], frameon=False, loc=0, fontsize='small')
for text in leg.get_texts():
    text.set_color(info_colors)
    plt.ylabel('˚C', color=info_colors)

# set extra yaxis label
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('˚F', color=info_colors)
ax2.tick_params('y', colors=info_colors)
```

[image: Plotted Temp Data]

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your plot to see if I could help... Would you be able to add the definitions of `t_mins` and `t_maxs` to your sample code?

Comment: Your code doesn't work `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 20), indices imply (2, 365)` You can `ax.set_xticks` to set xticks, but I have a feeling that you might want to `ax1.set_xlim` to limit the values that shows on the x-axis

Comment: @Cheng, I've corrected the code and tested it to ensure it's working. t_mins / t_maxs was legacy code and has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the minor labels, put the following code after `ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))`:

```
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor', colors=info_colors)
```

[image]

Comment: that's fantastic. I've also figured out how to use the left y-axis to create a right y-axis in ˚F. You will simply apply the conversion ˚F = (˚C * 9/5) + 32. So if you had a column of temp values, you would use broadcasting and say, `faren_vals = (celsius_vals * 9/5) + 32` and all of the cells in the celsius_vals column would be converted. Then use `set_ylim(faren_vals)` to set the right y-axis limits.